# Select an array based on an variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have multipled arrays and a `selector` variable, now I want to choose and display the corresponding array to in console e.g.:
`if (selector == 1) {console.dir(array1)};`
However I feel using many if clauses to select an array is unefficent and I need a better approach.

Comment: Use arrays of arrays or objects with keys. You should never have unknown variable names.

Comment: Still a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript (despite the question being reopened)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an array of arrays and use that (your selector is basically the integer index of the array you want in the main array):

```
var masterArray = [ [1,2] , [3,4] ];

var selector = 1;

console.log(masterArray[selector]) //logs the second item [3,4]

console.log(masterArray[selector - 1]) //logs the first one [1,2] - use this if your selector is not zero indexed
```

EDIT : Elaborating on @Xufox comment on the question

You can also use an object and access your arrays like this:

```
var myArrays = {
    array1: [1,2],
    array2: [3,4]
}

var selector = 1;

console.log(myArrays['array'+selector]) //[1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use an object instead. Like so:

```
var selectors = {
sel1: [
  0,
  5
],
sel2: [
  5,
  6
]
};
var i = 1;
console.log(selectors["sel" + i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create nested arrays(array of arrays) in javascript like the way below if you want:

var arr=[];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  arr[i]=new Array([i*2,i*3]);
}

// Then using the selector you can retrieve your desired value:


 var selector=1;

alert(arr[selector]);//2,3
alert (arr[3]); //6,9
alert(arr[2]); //4,6
alert(arr[2][0][0]); //4
alert(arr[2][0][1]); //6
```